# Insert html into rich text area

Tags: apex, trigger, class

Is there any way to insert html into rich text area without using VF page.
HTML page is a dynamic which will reflect a value of account owner and rich text area field is on Account.

Comment: Which HTML element/tag you are trying to insert?

Comment: actually there are lots of HTML tags it's a small page showing account owner's details.

Comment: Can post a screen shot as to where you are trying to display these html tags

Comment: in which way you want to insert HTML tag in Rich Text area.??

Comment: Task is on account Detail page the Rich text area field will show a HTML tags/page